# Google AMP amp-sidebar & fixed positioned z-index

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

I have a header with position:fixed and I'm trying to implement amp-sidebar component.

AMP is creating the -amp-fixedLayer adding `style="top: calc(0px); pointer-events: initial; z-index: 10000;"`
 to fix scrolling performance in Safari (*"[FixedLayer]" "In order to improve scrolling performance in Safari, we now move the element to a fixed positioning layer:"* )

The problem is that since amp-sidebar component has a `z-index:9999!important` in their styles,  the fixedLayer is displayed in top of the sidebar.

I thought about wrapping amp-sidebar and then I could add the `z-index` I want, but the parent tag for an amp-sidebar can only be 'body'

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please include a reference to the library and version you are talking about (is this it: https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-sidebar/)?

Comment: Also, please include some code samples, as I could not find any reference to `z-index:9999`. If you can't modify the `z-index` of an element which *must* be a child of `<body>`, then you're likely out of luck.

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Yes, that's the component I'm talking about. If you inspect the element, you will see that their css has the z-index:9999!important. (here you can find the pic: http://postimg.org/image/ccjiladm9/). What I'm trying to do is have a stick header and a sidebar as off-canvas menu.

Comment: @PraveenKumar AMP is the Accelerated Mobile Pages Project from Google https://www.ampproject.org/

Comment: The sidebar does not have to take up the entire height of the window. But we need to see an example of your progress before being able to propose an alternative solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JamesIves I manage to move things around and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and after fiddling a bit I found a way to edit the Z-index of my header.

Amp puts what z-index it thinks is needed but you can tweak those values. For instance:

```
    header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -2000;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
        color: white;
    }
```

This is the CSS code of my header, the trick here is to use a negative z-index. Amp will take its default value, add the z-index from the style (negative in this case) and put the result in the CSS.

So in my case the calculated z-index of the header is less than the sidebar's and therefore the sidebar gets on top of the header.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I upvoted this because I thought this was the answer, but it seems this hides the whole page when the amp page is loaded via Google cache.

Answer (score 0):

## Fairly limited options

Considering that a portion of the intent behind amp is to push developers toward a UI standard (where the sidebar should always take the entire height of the window), you'll have to lightly break it.

note: Apparently jQuery is not an option.

#### Use margin on the sidebar

```
amp-sidebar {
    margin-top: 10em;
    margin-left: 5vw;
}
```

### Ultimately, submit a bug report here:

https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/issues/new

### Roll your own amp

1. Submit a bug
2. Fork the github repo.
3. Patch the bug by setting the sidebar z-index higher.
4. Use your patched repo.
5. Submit a pull request to the master amp repo (fixes bug you reported).

That's really the right way to handle these scenarios.

Comment: Don't use em or vw sizes for amp, you probably don't need a margin-left, test it like crazy before you run with it.

Comment: It's not possible to use jQuery because it's an AMP constraint.

Comment: The sidebar does not have to take up the entire height of the window.

Comment: @JayGray From a design standpoint, I agree. However, the definition and intent of these sidebars and amp, is for the sidebar to appear to be part of the native smartphone os for navigation purposes. An effect which would be ruined if the sidebar was not full-height. https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-side-nav